# Coincidence or rule?

Tags: terminology, android, naming, clr

I was reading about Assemblies (modules, which Microsoft CLR works with). The Assembly contains so called Manifest, which by definition describes a set of files in the Assembly.

I know that Android applications also contain a file called Manifest, which also describes a set of files contained in the application.

Is this simply a coincidence? Or are there some commonly accepted rules in software development to name "special" files?

Comment: The same term is also used for Java .JAR files.

Comment: @user281377, that's already Google, Microsoft and Sun/Oracle?!

Comment: I'm pretty sure the terminology comes from the term *shipping manifest*, which wikipedia describes as: "Manifest, a document listing the cargo, passengers, and crew of a ship, aircraft, or vehicle, for the use of customs and other officials."

Comment: As far as I know Java was the first one to call it "manifest" (at least of the three that where mentioned). And since it's a fitting name (similar to a shipping manifest, it describes the content of a package), others just used the same term for similar files.

Comment: There is certainly no rule, but i wouldn't say it was coincidence either, they are clearly related concepts so its natural to use the same word - i.e. put it down to English semantics

Comment: It's neither a coincidence nor a rule, just a good descriptive word to capture a concept. It's the same reason words like 'factory', 'facade', 'token', 'agent' are ubiquitous in software development.

Comment: @Baqueta: You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @Baqueta, I absolutely agree. Or I'll post all comments together as one BIG answer ))

Comment: @superM - just beat you to it.  :-)  And I answered it as community wiki, so I won't pick up any reputation points from it.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner Maybe I should've, though it was just an educated guess so felt a little uneasy about doing so. Oh well, next time. :)

Comment: @GlenH7, thanks anyway ))) I'm happy my question is answered now!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So you can mark this one as answered, these three comments accurately summarize things:

Baqueta's comment:

```
I'm pretty sure the terminology comes from the term shipping manifest, which wikipedia 
describes as: "Manifest, a document listing the cargo, passengers, and crew of a ship, 
aircraft, or vehicle, for the use of customs and other officials."
```

Joachim Sauer's comment:

```
As far as I know Java was the first one to call it "manifest" (at least of the three 
that where mentioned). And since it's a fitting name (similar to a shipping manifest, 
it describes the content of a package), others just used the same term for similar files.
```

MattDavey's comment:

```
It's neither a coincidence nor a rule, just a good descriptive word to capture a concept.
It's the same reason words like 'factory', 'facade', 'token', 'agent' are ubiquitous in 
software development.
```